# quadratic formula in a floating-point system

Tags: floating-point, precision

Assuming we are solving the quadratic equation ax<sup>2</sup> + bx + c = 0 with a = 1.22, b = 3.34, and c = 2.28, using a normalized floating-point system with base β = 10 and precision p = 3.

1. What is the calculated value of b<sup>2</sup> − 4ac?
2. What is the exact value of the discriminant in real (exact) arithmetic?
3. What is the relative error in the calculated value of the discriminant?

Tried by solving:

```
1. fl(b · b) = fl(3.34 · 3.34) = fl(11.1556) = 11.2
   fl(4 · a · c) = fl(fl(4 · a) · c) = fl(fl(4 · 1.22) · 2.28) = 
   fl(fl(4.88) · 2.28) =
   fl(4.88 · 2.28) = fl(11.1264) = 11.1
   fl(11.2 − 11.1) = 0.1 (answer)

2. b^2 − 4ac = 11.1556 − 11.1264 = 0.0292 

3. b = (0.1 − 0.0292)/0.0292 = 0.0708/0.0292 ≈ 2.42466
```

Comment: Please show us what you tried, and tell us specifically where you're you're stuck.  Then we might be able to help you, without feeling dirty that we've just given you the answer, and prevented you from learning anything.

Comment: Does the normalized floating-point system with precision p = 3 guarantee correctly-rounded results, or does it just truncate?

Comment: Re “Tried to find it online but failed”: You know the class you are taking is teaching you to calculate these things yourself, not to search for them online, right? There are infinitely many mathematical problems, so they cannot all be online, even with today’s massive storage capabilities. You need to be able to figure things out using knowledge, not look them up.

Answer (score 1):

If the 2nd order polynomial `ax2 + bx + c = 0` is solved with:

```
(-b ± sqrt(b*b - 4*a*c))/(2*a)
```

and `a = 1.22`, `b = 3.34`, and `c = 2.28`, with *base β = 10 and precision p = 3*, we have

```
(-3.34 ± sqrt(3.34*3.34   - 4*1.22*2.28))/(2*1.22)
(-3.34 ± sqrt(r3(11.1556) - r3(11.1264)))/(2*1.22)
(-3.34 ± sqrt(   11.2     -    11.1    ))/ 2.44
(-3.34 ± sqrt(   0.100                 ))/ 2.44
(-3.34 ± r3(     0.3162277660168...    ))/ 2.44
(-3.34 ±         0.316                 ) / 2.44
```

> a) What is the calculated value of `b2 − 4ac`?

If `r3()` is a round-to nearest of 3 significant decimal places:

```
d1 = 0.1
```

> (b) What is the exact value of the [discriminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant) in real (exact) arithmetic?

```
d0 = 3.34*3.34 - 4*1.22*2.28
```

> (c) What is the relative error in the calculated value of the discriminant?

```
rel_err = (d1 - d0)/d0
```

---

Instead of `b*b - 4*a*c`, code could use the mathematically equal:

```
(b - 2*sqrt(a*c)) * (b + 2*sqrt(a*c))
```

and arrive at a different *computed* discriminant.

```
(3.34 - 2*sqrt(1.22*2.28)) * (3.34 + 2*sqrt(1.22*2.28))
(3.34 - 2*sqrt(r3(2.7816)) * (3.34 + 2*sqrt(r3(2.7816))
(3.34 - 2*sqrt(   2.78   ) * (3.34 + 2*sqrt(   2.78   )
(3.34 - 2*r3(1.6673332...) * (3.34 + 2*r3(1.6673332...)
(3.34 - 2*   1.67        ) * (3.34 + 2*   1.67        )
(3.34 -   3.34           ) * (3.34 + 3.34             )
          0                * ...
          0
```

---

The *key* is that subtraction of near floating point values risks severe computational precision loss.

Comment: Re “subtraction of near floating point values risks severe computational precision loss”: Subtraction of near floating-point values has zero error, per Sterbenz’ Lemma. The issue is merely that whatever error is already in the operands may be huge relative to the result.